# Elasticsearch NEST v.5.0.1 sort by GeoDistance error

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I faced a problem using NEST in my Web Api Project for sorting by GeoDistance.
I have:

- server with Elasticsearch v5.1.1 (working good)
- simple .NET Web Api application with NEST v5.0.1 installed (basic CRUD and
  search operations are working good)

Yesterday I decided to implement sorting by GeoDistance, however all possible solutions I had led me to this exception in Search/Sort requests:

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on
>   POST: /activities/activity/_search
>   Audit trail of this API call:
>
> [1] BadResponse: Node: http://MY_SERVER_IP:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.3129217
>   ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed" CausedBy: "Type:
>
> illegal_argument_exception Reason:
>
> ## "failed to find mapper for [geoposition] for geo distance based sort""
>
> OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.d__9`1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Users\russ\source\elasticsearch-net-5.x\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection.cs:line
>   199
>
> Request:
>
> force it to be set on the response.>
>
> Response:
>
> ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

My Model:

```
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = nameof(Id), Name = "activity")]
public class Activity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [GeoPoint(Name = "geoposition")]
    public GeoLocation Geoposition { get; set; }
    [Date(Name = "date_published")]
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
}
```

My NEST client initialization:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(_node)
                .DefaultIndex(_defaultIndex)
                .MapDefaultTypeIndices(m => m.Add(typeof(Activity), _defaultIndex));
ElasticClient _client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

I tried two different mapping approaches, because I didn't really get how to do this in a new NEST client:

1. `_client.Map<Activity>(m => m.AutoMap().Properties(p => p.GeoPoint(geo => geo.Name(n => n.Geoposition))));`
2. `_client.Map<Activity>(m => m.Properties(p => p.GeoPoint(geo => geo.Name(n => n.Geoposition))));`

My current query (give me error described above):

```
var result = await _client.SearchAsync<Activity>(s => s.Index(_defaultIndex)
//I removed search query to analyze only sorting problem
                        .Sort(
                            ss =>
                                ss.Descending(p => p.DatePublished)
                                    .GeoDistance(
                                        g => g
                                            .Field(p => p.Geoposition)
                                            .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Plane)
                                            .Unit(DistanceUnit.Kilometers)
                                            .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
                                            .PinTo(pin))));
```

My mapping response from elasticsearch server:

```
{
  "activities": {
    "mappings": {
      "activity": {
        "properties": {
          "date_published": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "geoposition": {
            "properties": {
              "lat": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "lon": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem? I can not understand why it's not working and why mapping is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The main rule I got using stackoverflow by far is: The problem was created by me, so solution is already inside me. Search for it.

If you ever face the same error check if you have an index creation code. I didn't have one. So my index and it's mapping was created on inserting of first document (found out with tests).

The answer is this missing string:

```
_client.CreateIndex(_defaultIndex, descriptor => descriptor.Mappings(ms => ms.Map<Activity>(m => m.AutoMap())));
```

right after elastic client initialized

```
ElasticClient _client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Comment: for `geo_point` field mappings, you need to explicitly map and ensure the mapping is created in the index before you send any documents to it

Comment: @RussCam , thank you for commenting. As far as I understand you are the one Russ from c:/users/russ :) you are right, I should definitely explicitly map my index to prevent possible problems in production, I read a lot about this recently.

Comment: I found that `Client.CreateIndex(IndexName, c => c.Mappings(m => m.Map(DocumentType, mm => mm.AutoMap())));` is not the same as `Client.CreateIndex(IndexName, c => c.Mappings(m => m.Map<DocumentType>(mm => mm.AutoMap())));`. The right way for a dynamic type(non generic) is  `Client.CreateIndex(IndexName, c => c.Mappings(m => m.Map(DocumentType, mm => mm.AutoMap(DocumentType))));`